# Getting error trying to run nsolid standalone

Tags: configuration, nsolid

I am attempting to profile an application standalone (i.e. on the same machine as a developer).  I'm not sure I'm configuring it right, but I do:

`NSOLID_PROXY=0.0.0.0:0 npm run myserverlauncher`

The application fires up and uses a random port for NSolid

Now, I want to fire up the nsolid console, and it starts but cannot find my machine.  I tried:

`npm start
NSOLID_PROXY=0.0.0.0:0 npm start 
NSOLID_PROXY=0.0.0.0:47020 npm start  (using the port given during launch)`

None of these can discover my server.

Any clues on how to troubleshoot the standalone configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid overload on your application when profiling you don't connect directly to N|Solid. We designed a Hub for use to gathering the information for profiling without any overload.

You'll need a `etcd` server running and the N|Solid Hub. Afterwards you point your application to connect to the Hub using `NSOLID_HUB` env var (note that `NSOLID_PROXY` is wrong).

We [have a very complete guide to run N|Solid](https://nodesource.com/blog/getting-started-with-the-nsolid-console/) in a standalone and development environment, take a look and also check out [the scripts used](https://gist.github.com/pmuellr/3854a1a7f17159b432e6#file-nsolid-install-sh) there to make it all work out of the box.

Feel free to reach us anytime!

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, that guide was exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.  I guess you only do the profiling locally without the hub as a proof-of-concept, right?

Comment: Followed your guide but am stack on getting it to see my server.

The proxy wants to load on 9000, but that port is well-known in the application. So I moved it to 10001 - using the files proxy/.nsolid-proxyc and console/.nsolid-proxyc - setting the "port" to 10001 but leaving others alone.  Fired up etcd, proxy and console.

The console launches, but cannot detect any programs. I'm launching like this:

NSOLID_HUB=4001 NSOLID_APPNAME=foo ~/nsolid/bin/nsolid programName

What else could be going wrong here? I am running El Capitan, 10.11.3, no firewall active, nsolid 1.2.1.

Comment: More info:  Used NODE_DEBUG=nsolid on the proxy launcher, and got these errors:  "nsolid agent incoming request: /v2/keys/nsolid/demo/<hex key>" - listener request contains a body - unable to parse request body, aborting request.

Comment: Is possible that the changes of ports could confuse etc or N|Solid Console. I could suggest move your app to a different port used by N|Solid (4001, 9000). If is impossible do that, I can replicate your settings and check where else we need to set the different port. (And sorry for the delay)